# Navigate to the file from output in the terminal - WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

Is it possible to tune WebStorm so that when I have something like this in my terminal window, then I just click on the filename and jump to it.

[image]

Comment: Try "Awesome Console" plugin -- maybe it can help here (it's a not full file path and line numbers are not separated from file extension ... so I'm not sure).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Webstorm does in fact *now* have this functionality.

Note that the bug about this functionality being missing (linked in another answer) has been marked as fixed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118566.

Answer (score 13):

Not possible using built-in terminal (please vote for [IDEA-118566](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118566) and [IDEA-154439](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154439)).

[Awesome Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/7677-awesome-console) plugin might be a solution; but it doesn't support built-in terminal (https://github.com/anthraxx/intellij-awesome-console/issues/23)

there is also [Output Link Filter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/7183-output-link-filter) plugin that provides similar functionality, but it looks outdated and (also) doesn't work in built-in terminal

**Update (2022)**:  [IDEA-118566](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118566) is already fixed, links should work. Please note that providing links for particular output needs adding specific logic handing such output. Thus, if you encounter missing links in a particular output, please file a separate issue request describing link output format and steps to reproduce such output.

Comment: Webstorm now has this functionality; if you follow the link for IDEA-118566 you'll see it is marked fixed.

Comment: Awesome Console mentioned above supports the built-in terminal in IntelliJ Community Edition

Comment: None of these options work for me since I'm using Webpack and the files I need to see are in my bundled dist folder. Webstorm automatically excludes Webpack bundle destination folders so I can't click or search for the link, and Awesome Console for some reason doesn't bring me to the actual bundled file in the dist folder, it brings me to the source code file (aka it's useless).

Answer (score 5):

It's not quite a single click solution, but what I do, is double click the text so that it auto selects and copies the path, including line and char numbers to clipboard. Then use the shortcut for `Goto File...`. Hit paste (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) then <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it will take you to the exact location.

For me, the shortcut for `Goto File...` is <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> - you can check your shortcut in the menu `Navigate` `->` `File...`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following format to output text in the terminal via `console.log` and the path will be clickable:

```
at ($FILE_FULL_PATH:$LINE_NUMBER:$SYMBOL_NUMBER)
```

Example with the full path to the file:

```
at (/home/ubuntu/project/index.js:12:55)
```

However, if you're running WebStorm with exact file path's project's folder, you can use the following format:

```
at (./project/index.js:12:55)
```

Comment: As infuriatingly limited as it is, this does work! The "at" needs to be at the beginning of the line. It cannot be in a JSON log line :( This seems to just be using the functionality to parse stack traces/error output.

Answer (score 3):

I installed [Awesome Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7677-awesome-console) plugin and with this plugin, all files and links in the console and terminal will be highlighted and can be clicked. Source code files will be opened in the IDE, other links with the default viewer/browser for this type.

You can jump to files from the terminal with `left click`

Answer (score 3):

Just select file path (dblclick) & press "shift" twice (search everywhere) & press "enter"...

Comment: This doesn't work if you're using Webpack and the file is in your bundled dist folder since Webstorm automatically excludes Webpack bundle destination folder.