# Error path not clickable in WebStorm terminal

Tags: terminal, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I recently switched from VS Code back to WebStorm.
There I have two different projects. Interestingly, in one of these I noticed that my error paths are not clickable and I am unable to interact with these and jump to the given code snippet. This really frustrates and hinders my development. However,  I am unable to spot any difference in plugins or any other things.

Most of the issues regarding this problem have been marked as solved or are very old (as old as 9 years), as seen in the following threads:

- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/10915468975634-Clicking-on-files-in-error-messages-not-working
- [Navigate to the file from output in the terminal - WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42389262/navigate-to-the-file-from-output-in-the-terminal-webstorm)
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118566

Error in Project A (not clickable):

[image: Example of non clickable file path in terminal]

Error in Project B (clickable):
[image]

The used WebStorm Version is 2023.3.2